# jQuery UI draggable not dragging for X axis in RTL page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, arabic

I am using the following:

jQuery v3.3.1

jQuery UI - v1.12.1 - 2018-10-16

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Have an HTML page with RTL in the html tag on top.
2. Include Jquery and Jquery ui with css files.
3. Enable draggable component for a div element on document ready.

> ```
> $("#element-helper").draggable({
>   handle: ".handle"
> });
> ```

```
<div id="element-helper">
  <div class="header">
    <i class="icon white note"></i>
    <h3 class="handle"> Element Insert</h3>
    <a class="close-styler"><i class="icon white delete"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Do you guys know any solution to this problem? I'v been searching but did not find a solution yet.

When i remove RTL from the html tag, it works fine. But my page and framework is rtl only.

Answer (score 1):

[Solved] I had to keep the element css to left direction for it to work properly even in RTL.

```
#element-helper {
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  min-height: 500px;
  width: 400px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```